# Oracle SQL Developer SQL History TimeStamp

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, date-formatting

I am wondering if there is way to modify how the Timestamp is presented in the SQL History window. Currently the timestamps show up as a string of numbers like this: 1525278069600. How can I get the date to display as something like 05/02/2018 11:53:00? I am using 4.0.3.16 ( I know its old). Thanks.

Comment: 4.0 is quite old have you tried in a more current version ?

Comment: On versión 17 you are able to change the date format. Check if this is possible in your versión on: Preferences -> DataBase -> NLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade, or, what @kris-rice and @Mike-Aguilar said above in their comments.

In current version:

[image]

What you're seeing is due to Bug 18183587, which was marked as fixed/released in 4.0.1.

But if you're going to upgrade, go all the way to 18.1.

Comment: My Timestamp Format is set as: MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF3 AM, but still showing the unix format. I am running 4.0.3.16, but maybe I will need to upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: @telamonides did you read the answer? You need to upgrade, your version has a bug where we are not properly formatting the date/time for humans

Comment: @telamonides it should be fixed in 4.0.1 - but I may have a typo in our bugdb where it was fixed in 4.1 and NOT 4.0.1 - the joys of software :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks very much like [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), calculating "something" from January 1, 1970.

Just

- in case of Unix time that something is seconds (see live example on Wikipedia: right now it is 1525276985, representing 2018-05-02T16:03:05Z
- in your case it seems to be expressed in milliseconds, as the number begins with the same 1525... thing, but has 3 more digits at the end.

Just for visuals:

```
1525276985    (Unix)
1525278069600 (yours)
```

(Now I have a feeling that this may not be what you have asked for, but it may still have some use)

Comment: I figured it was unix time, but I was wondering how to change it to something human readable.